# Plotly Scatterpolar Color Scheme is not changing

Tags: python, plot, colors, plotly, radar-chart

I would like to change the color scheme for my radar graph (using plotly's ScatterPolar). When I change the colorscale in markers, it has no effect on the color scheme, and I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code with an example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
def customRadarPlot(parameters,df,categorycol,listofcategories,showlegend=True,axislimit=None):
    """
    parameters: (list) of all parameters on the outer circle
    df: scaled dataframe including the category column. all columns except the category column should be numerical
    categorycol: (string) name of category column
    listofcategories: (list) of all categories you want to plot
    showLegend: True or False
    axistlimit: (float) of maximum value on axis
    """
    fig = go.Figure()
    for cat in listofcategories:
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
            r=list(np.array(df[df[categorycol]==cat])[0]),
            marker = dict(cmin = 0,cmax = 1,autocolorscale=False,colorscale='Blackbody'),
            theta=parameters,
            fill='toself',
            name=cat))
        fig.update_layout(
            polar=dict(radialaxis=dict(visible=True,range=[0, None])),showlegend=True)
    fig.show()
#Example: 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
iris = load_iris()
iris_data = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(iris.data)
iris_data = np.hstack((iris_data, iris.target.reshape(-1,1)))
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(data=iris_data, columns=iris.feature_names+ ["FlowerType"])
iris_df.tail()
irisparameters=list(iris_df.columns)
iriscategories=list(iris_df['FlowerType'].unique())
customRadarPlot(irisparameters,iris_df,'FlowerType',iriscategories)
```

Comment: I tried running your code, and what I get is a polygonal radar chart, but with a continuous color scheme to it. In this case, I think you can only draw a single color on the polygonal surface. If you want to use a single color, you need to specify `color='red'`.